# How to move logic out of views and into controller in Rails

Tags: ruby, model-view-controller, view, controller, logic

I am writing an [imageboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imageboard) in Ruby on Rails.

I have a form for creating new posts. In that form, there is logic to figure out whether the post was created from board#show or topic#show and act accordingly. It is:

```
  <% if @board != nil %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :board_id, :value => @board.id %>
  <% end %>

  <% if @topic != nil %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :topic_id, :value => @topic.id %>
  <% end %>
```

The form is rendered on board#show and topic#show with this piece of code:

```
<%= render :partial => 'posts/form'%>
```

Should I move that logic to the controller? How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is, in the view, it's probably fine. However, you could (possibly, depending on your app) refine it a little by putting the board/topic information in the URL using nested routes. Routes that would look something like this:

```
/boards/4/posts
/topics/133/posts
```

Then your "*is it from a board or a post*" logic could happen in your PostsController. Again, whether or not this is 'better' is dependent on your requirements, but that's an alternative way of approaching this.

As a side note, you can slim down your conditionals a little. `if @board` is the same as `if @board != nil` (unless you have a special case for `@board` being `false`. `nil` and `false`  will both evaluate as false).

Comment: Your first idea wouldn't be too clean because I use the board title in the url, not the id.

I ended up going with your second idea and just using if @board and keeping everything else.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's necessary to put it in the controller. I would use `:locals`. So in `board#show`:

```
<%= render :partial => 'posts/form', :locals => {:resource => @board} %>
```

Do the same in `topic#show`, but using `@topic`. Then in your form partial:

```
<%= f.hidden_field "#{resource.model_name.downcase}_id", :value => resource.id %>
```

There are probably more elegant ways to get the model_name, but that's the direction I'd take it.

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider a polymorphic relationship for this one. I'm not sure if it is a good fit, but it might be worth a try.

Otherwise, it's fine too pass nils. You can just do:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :board_id, :value => @board.try(:id) %>
<%= f.hidden_field :topic_id, :value => @topic.try(:id) %>
```

Come to think of it, ideally the controller should assign the fields to whatever you have in `f` and then the code should just be:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :board_id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :topic_id %>
```

Just do `@post.board_id = @board.id` in `board#show` and the equivalent code for `topic#show`. You can even do `@post = @board.posts.build` and that should assign the id automatically.